# Bootstrap nav collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my bootstrap navbar collapse at a different width but changing the

```
 //** Number of columns in the grid.
@grid-columns:                12;
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width:           30px;
// Navbar collapse
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
@grid-float-breakpoint:       @screen-sm-min;
//** Point at which the navbar begins collapsing.
@grid-float-breakpoint-max:   (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1);
```

just makes it fold on to two rows at different widths instead of collapsing and showing the hamburger icon. Is there something else I need to change in order to make it collapse down and show the icon?

I've changed it now to @screen-md-min

and it just deforms more :/ .. the width I want it to open and collapse at are the width of a desktop which is the md class but it doesn't seem to work at all :/

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `LESS variables` in `variables.less`  The responsive break points are set around line 200:

```
@screen-xs:                  480px;
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs;

// Small screen / tablet
@screen-sm:                  768px;
@screen-tablet:              @screen-sm;

// Medium screen / desktop
@screen-md:                  992px;
@screen-desktop:             @screen-md;

// Large screen / wide desktop
@screen-lg:                  1200px;
@screen-lg-desktop:          @screen-lg;

// So media queries don't overlap when required, provide a maximum
@screen-xs-max:              (@screen-sm - 1);
@screen-sm-max:              (@screen-md - 1);
@screen-md-max:              (@screen-lg - 1);
```

Then set the collapse value for the navbar using the *@grid-float-breakpoint* variable at about line 232.  By default it's set to  *@screen-tablet* .  If you want you can use a pixel value, but I prefer to use the LESS variables.

OR

- Visit http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables
- Change @navbarCollapseWidth in the formfield
- Customize the collapsing point
- Customize the @grid-float-breakpoint variable
- Click "Compile and Download".

OR

Simply you can use a CSS media query. the breakpoint is here 1280 pixels:

<kbd>**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/132348)**</kbd>

css

```
body {
    padding-top:70px;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I supposed to change anything else to get the hamburger logo to show up. I just get a blank nav at the break point. Thanks for any help!